# LDAP query for group membership

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to find an AD query to test if User A is part of Group B.

User A is member of Group A which is member of Group B; hence, User A is really a member of Group B.

I have tried looking at the information from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28VS.85%29.aspx, but this looks like it's starting the search from the User and going down.  I need to be able to start from the Group and crawl the child objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, and using VB.NET or C# as your programming language, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // find the group in question
   GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

   if(group != null)
   {
      bool isUserMemberOfThatGroup = user.IsMemberOf(group);
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!